# "Also by this author" list

Tags: author

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Also by (my name)
------------------
Book Number 1
Another Book
And One More
```

How would I go about doing this?

- I want the "Also by..." in perhaps `\textsf{}`.
- I want the name to be independent of `\author{}`.

Comment: Independent means different font style or anything else? :)

Comment: @Mannie No, it means "it isn't the same as what's in `\author{}`".

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly! :)

`\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Also by John Smith\par
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\par
Book Number 1\par
Another Book\par
And One More\par
\end{document}`

Greetings

Comment: +1 for not reading between the lines

Comment: That totally works~!